# Javascript - Where to put initialization data

Tags: javascript, architecture, initialization

Despite that I feel like this is a strange question, I would like to know what is the common practice when it comes to the initialization of JS objects, services and similiar stuff.

To me, it feels a little weird to bloat a source file with unsightly stuff like this:

```
var initObject = {
  foo: {
    some: 'nice',
    data: 'overhere'
  },

  bar: {
    ate: 42
  }
}
```

In order to use this for initialization

(I am using this to create large table grids, so the code bloats actually even more)

```
function awesomeFunc(data){
    doSomeStuffwithData();
}

var needed = initObject.foo;

awesomeFunc(needed);
```

Should I store such data serverside? Or should I move it into a separate file?
Is there even any standard?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways. More to come in ECMA6.

First of all, have you considered using a constructor function? Because right now you are just manipulating one object, if you wanted to have two. You would have to write initObject2 with the same internal values.

```
var InitObject = function () {
      this.foo: {
        some: 'nice',
        data: 'overhere',
      },
      this.bar: {
        ate: 42
      }
}
```

Then you can use the **new** keyword to create a new object.

```
var panda = new InitObject();
```

This essentially does what you wanted. But now you can create many of them.

```
var needed = panda.foo;
awesomeFunc(needed);
```

You could use a prototype function to get "needed".

```
var InitObject = function () {
          this.foo: {
            some: 'nice',
            data: 'overhere',
          },
          this.bar: {
            ate: 42
          }
    }
InitObject.prototype.getFoo = function () {
return this.foo;
};
```

Now just pass the prototype function into your awesomeFunc.

```
awesomeFunc(getFoo());
```

I find this pretty clean. Using the .prototype. also saves memory because all **new** InitObject will be using that function.

I personally go on github and look through the code of those guys who are much better than me at programming and at structuring code. Take a look at this if you want to see some really clean and easy to follow code:
[lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.js)

**EDIT: Don't forget the `this` keyword in front of your properties!**
*(Otherwise the property will become a global object or overwrite existing objects with the same name)*